# iptables blocking local connection to mongodb

Tags: mongodb, iptables

I have a VM (Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS) with mongodb (2.0.4) that I want to restrict with iptables to only accepting SSH (in/out) and nothing else.
This is how my setup script looks like to setup the rules:

```
#!/bin/sh

# DROP everything
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP

# input
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT  # accept all ports for local conns

# output
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT  # ssh
```

But with these rules activated, I can't connect to mongodb locally.

```
ubuntu ~ $ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.0.4
connecting to: test
Fri Mar 28 09:40:40 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1 shell/mongo.js:84
exception: connect failed
```

Without them, it works fine. Is there any special firewall case one needs to consider when deploying mongodb?

I tried installing mysql, and it works perfectly for local connections.
SSH works as exepected (can connect from outside and inside).

The iptables rules looks like this once set:

```
ubuntu ~ $ sudo iptables -nvL
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 8 packets, 1015 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  449  108K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       127.0.0.1            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
   32  2048 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP 27 packets, 6712 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  379  175K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
```

Comment: I noticed that if I add an OUTPUT rule for port 27017 it works.. question is why? I don't want to have it open without understanding why or leaving it potentially exposed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Outbound traffic must be accepted for the loopback (127.0.0.1) as well.

Adding this made it work:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 1):

You migth want to try, substituting the line

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
```

With

```
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: I tried this, unfortunately the same problem as before..
This is how the rule looks like when applied:

    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0