# mongodb service cannot start

Tags: linux, mongodb, manjaro

mongodb service cannot start with `systemctl start mongodb.service`, it would ask for a password. After then when I try `mongo` command, it throws :

`MongoDB shell version v3.6.2
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2018-03-18T16:05:39.307+0700 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2018-03-18T16:05:39.307+0700 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed`

I've been through all google page 1 solution but did nothing, also I try another query, but still again dont work for me, uninstall & install again also didnt work. My current OS distribution is Linux Manjaro.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That's not a programming question, voting to close as off-topic. Make sure you check the logfiles though, because above output just confirms what it's not running, there's little actual info in it.

Comment: bro you aint helping with that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Type "Mongod" in the terminal to start MongoDB
and then open another terminal and type mongo to start the shell.
This works fine for me.

Comment: The answer can be “don’t do that”, but it should also include “try this instead”. Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.

Answer (score 0):

The connection refused error sounds like a firewall issue.

1. I would check the appropriate logs for the real reason. In Linux check /var/log/system or /bar/log/messages or other files in that location.
2. If it turns out firewall issue or /etc/hosts blocking, the allow/open the appropriate port in.

**Update**:

**Opening** firewall (iptables for MongoDB port).  Type sudo before the following commands and put  of where the request is coming from.

```
iptables -A INPUT -s <ip-address> -p tcp --destination-port 27017 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A OUTPUT -d <ip-address> -p tcp --source-port 27017 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

**Background ** 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-linux-iptables-firewall/

**Update 2**: Add this additional rule to your firewall and type "sudo" in front of it : Outbound traffic must be accepted for the loopback (127.0.0.1) as well.  credits go to: [iptables blocking local connection to mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22707899/iptables-blocking-local-connection-to-mongodb)

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Hi thanks for replying, but I dont used to see my system log, would you like for me to post the last couple of line of my mongo log? Also how to open the port in Linux, thank you.

Comment: Yep. Post the logs and change ur IP address to xxx xxx xxx and other sensitive data. I will update the answer for the firewall rules

Comment: Here you go https://text-share.com/view/c14ff269 I dont find any IP address anyway.

Comment: This shows that mongodb is running fine. Can you run this command in the command line  that searches iptables keyword for the messages logs:  [sudo grep "iptables" /var/log/messages]

Comment: and [sudo grep "iptables" /var/log/kern.log] which is searching the keg.log file for iptables

Comment: First make the changes reflected above under update 2, then past the logs in last two comments if problems persist.

Comment: hey man thank you for keeping up with my question, but today (after some os update) my mongodb is up again. I thought I have to do clean install os.